# How to get the current page number of dataTable using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, datatable, richfaces, datascroller

I have tried the solutions provided in 
[rich:dataTable paging - marking visited pages of rich:datascroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422150/richdatatable-paging-marking-visited-pages-of-richdatascroller)
but it didn't work with rich faces 4.3.4.

I have also tried page attribute of data scroller. Here's my code implementing page attribute of datascroller.

```
 <h:form id="mainForm">
     <rich:dataScroller for="itemDataTable" maxPages="30" execute="itemDataTable" page="#{itemsController.pageIndex}"/>                                 
     <rich:dataTable rowKeyVar="rkVar" rows="15" id="itemDataTable" value="#{itemsController.itemDM}" var="r">
     <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText id="pageNumberOutPutText" value="#{itemsController.pageIndex}"/>
     </f:facet>
        <h:column id="setValue">
            <h:inputText id="finalItem" valueChangeListener="#{itemsController.recalculate()}" value="#{r.items.prices}"/>
        </h:column>
        ...
        ...
    <!-- other columns --> 
    </rich:dataTable>
    <rich:dataScroller for="itemDataTable" maxPages="30" execute="itemDataTable" page="#{itemsController.pageIndex}"/>                                      
</h:form>
```

I have respective getters and setters in my itemsController class and with following scope:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
```

with pageIndex intially set to 1.

```
private int pageIndex = 1;
```

And I tried to alert the current page number using:

```
alert('You are in page : ' + $('#mainForm\\:itemDataTable\\:pageNumberOutPutText').val());
```

But it alerts only 1. Also the outputText in the datatable footer shows only 1 even if I click next page or click other pages.

Above all, all I wanted to do is alert the current page number using JQuery. I also dont want to use getters and setters for this, if possible. I really wanted to know how to get the current page number using Jquery.

Comment: I have manually solved the problem using click event of the datascroller from Jquery. But it would be really helpful if somebody can show me the alternate of pageIndexVar in richfaces 4.3.4 or similar.

Comment: Does it help if you add render="pageNumberOutPutText" to the rich:dataScroller?

Comment: Oh, I feel ashamed. Thank you. It solved my problem.

Comment: OK, thanks. Converting to an answer than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify region to re-render with ajax request to update appropriate parts of the view. E.g.:

`<rich:dataScroller render="pageNumberOutPutText"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The current page number is in the JS object that backs the datascroller. You can get it with:

```
#{rich:component('scrollerId')}.currentPage
```